# How to call setter methods in Java based on variable name

Tags: java

Let's say that I have defined these variables

```
RDFNode bd= soln.get(SparqlConstants.BD) ;
RDFNode alias = soln.get(SparqlConstants.ALIAS) ;
RDFNode thumbnail = soln.get(SparqlConstants.THUMBNAIL) ;
RDFNode battingSide = soln.get(SparqlConstants.BATTING_SIDE) ;
```

And then for each one of them, I have to set in a value in a setter method like this

```
if (bd!= null)
   player.setBirthDate(bd.asNode().getIndexingValue().toString());
```

Is there a way to have a generic method, that I pass the value and the method to call so generically this could be done in Java?

Answer (score 1):

With `reflection` you can do this:

```
public void set(RDFNode node, String propertyName) {

    String methodName = "set" + propertyName; // <-- propertyName must be in upper CamelCase

    String value = node.asNode().getIndexingValue().toString();

    Method setMethod = player.getClass().getMethod(methodName, String.class);
    setMethod.invoke(player, value);
}
```

Comment: `String methodName = "set" + propertyName;` will not work even if name is in camel case - you have to capitalize the name. but Apache bean utils takes care of that

Answer (score 0):

You can create a method and reuse it :

```
public String getIndexingValue(RDFNode node)
{
   return node.asNode().getIndexingValue().toString();
}

if(bd != null)
  player.setBirthDate(getIndexingValue(bd));
... and so on ...
```

Comment: if i understood correctly, OP wanted to replace the setter `setBirthDate()` ,not the getter

Comment: @sharonbn But I not using getter anywhere, I have mentioned setter only.

Comment: you created a new `getIndexingValue()` getter instead of addressing explicit call to setter `setBirthDate()`

Answer (score 0):

The only way to access/invoke a class/method based on textual name is through reflection.  However, if your POJO adheres to the Java bean standard of getter/setter names, there are libraries, such as [Apache Commons Beanutils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-beanutils/) that can hide away the reflection implementation.

Answer (score 0):

You could define a generic method on the player object and set the values using reflection.

```
public void setGenericValue(methodName, param) {
   this.getClass().getMethod(methodName, ...
}
```

Examples in this stackoverflow post:
[How do I invoke a Java method when given the method name as a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/160970/how-do-i-invoke-a-java-method-when-given-the-method-name-as-a-string)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a method as -

```
private void setBirthDate(Player player, RDFNode obj) {
        if (obj != null) {
               player.setBirthDate(obj.asNode().getIndexingValue().toString());
        }
    }
```

And then call it like -

```
RDFNode bd= soln.get(SparqlConstants.BD);
setBirthDate(player, bd);
```